# How to create array of objects from the same child component form in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, material-ui, react-hooks

I am trying to create an array of objects from a child component form having same fields.

I am using react hooks to store the state and using for loop in JSX repeated the child component.

Flow of the App => Parent --> 2 same Child but different input --> create object array --> return to parent array of objects

UI

[Image of the form UI where Delivery Contact is same Child Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Qi81.png)

Parent Code

```
      {[...Array(2)].map((e, i) => {

        const deliveryContactDetails = deliveryContact => {
          // deliveryRef[i].current.sendData()
          console.log(deliveryContact);
        }

        return (
          <React.Fragment>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
          <FormLabel component="legend">
            Delivery Contact Person : ({i+1})
          </FormLabel>
          </Grid>

          <DeliveryContact formNo={i+1} ref={deliveryRef[i] = useRef()} saveDelivery={deliveryContactDetails} ></DeliveryContact>

          </React.Fragment>
        )

      })}

    </React.Fragment>
```

Child Code

```
    const formNo = props.formNo;

    const [values, setValues] = useState({...contactObj})

    const handleInputChange = ({ target }) => {
        const { name, value } = target;
        setValues({...values, [name]: value})
    };

    useImperativeHandle(ref,() => ({
        sendData() {
          props.saveDelivery(values);
        }
    }));

    return(
        <React.Fragment>

            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                <TextField
                select
                fullWidth
                margin="dense"
                id="salutation"
                name={"salutation" + formNo}
                fullWidth
                onChange={handleInputChange}
                value={values.salutation}
                variant="outlined"
                label="Salutation"
                >
                <MenuItem value={`Mr.`}>Mr.</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={`Ms.`}>Ms.</MenuItem>
                </TextField>
            </Grid>

            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                <TextField
                id="deliveryContactName"
                name={"name" + formNo}
                label="Delivery Contact Name"
                fullWidth
                variant="outlined"
                margin="dense"
                onChange={handleInputChange}
                value={values.deliveryContactName}
                inputProps={{
                    maxLength: 40
                }}
                />
            </Grid>
  )
```

Required Object

```
"contacts" : [
        {
            "name": "asdasdas123da",
            "phone" : 9898989898,
            "email": "test@mailinator.com",
            "designation" : "Some Manager" ,
            "salutation" : "Mr"
        },
        {
            "name": "asdasdas",
            "phone" : 9898989898,
            "email": "test@mailinator.com",
            "designation" : "Some Manager" ,
            "salutation" : "Mr"
        }
     ]
```

Comment: Maybe you should consider using: Redux ( https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react ) or any other state management library